# Bar animations in 2.0.0-beta/dev are not working for me

Tags: chart.js

An error i get in chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: easingFunction is not a functionanimation.render @ Chart.js:1423Chart.animationService.startDigest @ Chart.js:1158Chart.animationService.digestWrapper @ Chart.js:1136
```

Options that I'm using:

```
    options: {animation:true, animationSteps: 60, animationEasing: easeOutQuart", responsive:true, maintainAspectRatio: false,}
```

Chart.js from branch is everything on it's default.

```
    Chart.defaults.global.animation = {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutQuart",
    onProgress: function() {},
    onComplete: function() {},
};

Chart.Animation = Chart.Element.extend({
    currentStep: null, // the current animation step
    numSteps: 60, // default number of steps
    easing: "", // the easing to use for this animation
    render: null, // render function used by the animation service

    onAnimationProgress: null, // user specified callback to fire on each step of the animation 
    onAnimationComplete: null, // user specified callback to fire when the animation finishes
});
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle set up?

Comment: @potatopeelings hmm...interesting, I can't get chart displayed http://jsfiddle.net/pvb1dgr8/1/

Comment: dunno if I have to enable animation in charts.js but according to chartjs 2-dev it should be on out of the box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `responsiveAnimationDuration`

```
...
options: {
    responsiveAnimationDuration: 5000,
    ...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5ebvocra/